# Android Navigation Drawer: Fragments vs Activitiy's

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

After reading up on documentation and discussions about Fragment's and Activity's, I think I got the picture clear.

Activities are supposed provide the user with a screen in which the user can work. Navigating to other screens generally destroy the activities.

Fragments are supposed to provide little or single functionality component(s), which can be used again in an Activity. The contents of a Fragment is supposed to be working independently from each other, and are thus reusable in multiple Activities.

Now while it all seems to make sense, I can't understand one thing:

If you create a new Android Application, and choose the option to create an Android Navigation Drawer application, why does the navigation drawer use Fragment's to display, instead of Activity's?

Comment: They recommend to use fragments instead of lot of activities.

Comment: @Aafaq Why? Essentially, each item in the navigation drawer is more likely to have complete different functionality than the other? Also, Fragment's are often used as part of Activity's. Then why use a Fragment as a full screen?

Comment: I don't think so you can have a smooth sliding drawer as a activity to overlap the other activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default template for creating Navigation Drawers in Android Studio gives you an activity with a container layout which will hold all of the fragments that you will use. The activity also handles the navigation events and initialization methods, so it isn't really contradicting what the Android documentation says. You could even reuse your fragments in a separate activity.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @dustendrob said but i can add something.

Fragments is the obvious answer and there's a why.
Navigation drawer has to work on an Activity in which he has to be handled. If we follow the normal way to do it, when you press on a navigation drawer item, it has to change the content of the activity adding a fragment on it. In this case you can press again navigation drawer (that is in the Activity) to change again the fragment.

If we consider the case of multiple activity, it means that you have to choose an activity that handle navigation drawer and call it everytime you want to change activities or create multiple handle for each activity.

Comment: Actually, creating the project lets the MainActivity extend from ActionBarActivity and handles the NavigationBar actions. 

But I do understand what you are saying. The NavigationDrawer activity itself contains Fragments (an Activity usually doesn't contain Activity's). Probably to 'keep' the NavigationDrawer in instead of reloading it each time you select an item from that drawer.